# 404 Error on Google App Engine Java Production

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I have been working with Google App Engine for last 3 years but never faced any such issue before. I have created a project using Spring-4 and Objectify.

The issue I am facing is that on local all URLs are working fine, but when I am deploying the same to the [appspot](http://swissinfos.appspot.com/) I am getting 404 errors on the URLs which needs to return the JSP pages, although the URL which should return the JSON or XML response those URL are working fine.

Appengine logs are also not providing any relevant information. I cannot understand just one thing that if it running fine locally why is it not working on [appspot](http://swissinfos.appspot.com/).

Following are my configuration files.

**appengine-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application>swissinfos</application>
  <version>2</version>

  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>

  <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
</appengine-web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
 For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package-->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.lumin.mytalk." />

<!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->
<mvc:annotation-driven /> 

<mvc:interceptors>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
<property name="paramName" value="lang"></property>
</bean>
</mvc:interceptors>


<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="locations">
<list>
    <value>WEB-INF/common.properties</value>
</list>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="converter" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
<property name="converters">
<list>
<bean class="com.lumin.mytalk.common.util.DozerConverter">
    <property name="mapper">
    <bean class="org.dozer.spring.DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingFiles">
        <value>/WEB-INF/classes/dozer/dozer-bean-mappings.xml</value>
    </property>
   </bean>
</property>
</bean>
</list>
</property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.lumin.mytalk." />

<!-- Application Message Bundle -->
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource">
<property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
<property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">

<filter>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/jsp/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**API Controller Sample**

```
@Controller
public class CategoryController extends AbstractGenericController{

@Autowired
private CategoryService categoryService;    

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = Path.Url.API + Path.Url.CATEGORY + Path.OperationUrl.CREATE, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json", "application/xml" })
public Object create(@RequestBody Category category) {
    Category isExisting = categoryService.getCategoryByName(category.getCategoryName());
    if (isExisting == null) {
        Long id = categoryService.createWithID(category);
        return new Response(null, STATUS.SUCCESS, "Category created successfully. Id :" + id);
    }else{
        return new Response(null, STATUS.FAILURE, "Category already exist. Please use update category function.");
    }
 }
}
```

**Web Controller Sample**

```
@Controller
public class LoginLogoutController {

@RequestMapping(value = Path.Url.LOGIN)
public String loginPage(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) boolean error, @RequestParam(value = "maidID", required = false) String maidID, ModelMap map) {
    if (error == true) {
        map.put("error", "You have entered an invalid username or password!");
    }if( maidID != null && !maidID.equals("")){
        map.addAttribute("maidID", maidID);
    }
    if((error == true) && (maidID != null && !maidID.equals(""))){
        map.put("error", "You have entered an invalid username or password!");
        map.addAttribute("maidID", maidID);
    }
    return Path.Jsp.LOGIN_PAGE;
 }
}
```

**GAE Log Entry**

> 2014-09-04 13:08:27.302 / 404 44ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0 module=default version=2
>   123.63.241.35 - - [04/Sep/2014:00:38:27 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 256 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0" "swissinfos.appspot.com" ms=44 cpu_ms=87 cpm_usd=0.000029 app_engine_release=1.9.10 instance=00c61b117c9c5e35c6e16583e442bfebd62dc8f0

Comment: @BatScream no I am not able to view the index.jsp file.

Comment: You say that the logs does not provide any relevant information, but could you paste a log-entry for a request anyway?

Comment: @nilsmagnus I have added the logs entry.